# file_get_contents and setting cookies

Tags: php, cookies, file-get-contents

In PHP I use `file_get_contents` to display the contents of files to the end user, as in:

```
$showfile = file_get_contents("http://website.org/dl.php?file=Filename");
echo ($showfile);
```

This passes through the `dl.php` program which gets the Filename as `$file` and includes the code below to set a cookie using the same Filename if one has not been set within the last two hours.

```
setcookie($file, "set", time() + 60*60*2*1, "/", "website.org");
```

Other code increments a download counter if the cookie has expired. It works fine when the link to Filename is an ordinary `href` link but not when it is displayed using `file_get_contents`. The counter increments on every page refresh showing that `dl.php` is being activated using that Filename but is failing to set the cookie in the proper way even though when I evalute the `setcookie` expression it returns `True`.

Have tried loads but not been able to overcome this problem.

Comment: Are you setting the cookie in `dl.php` and not in the script that calls it? If so that won't make any difference to the script you are running for the user - the HTTP fetch in `file_get_contents()` is entirely separate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
setcookie($file, "set", time() + 60*60*2*1, "/", "website.org");
```

to

```
ob_start();
setcookie($file, "set", time() + 60*60*2*1, "/", "website.org");
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions. I tried ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); but they made no difference.